# what does this @Profile("!json") mean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

We are using this and would like to know what it actually does, looked on the web for detailed explanation but didn;t find anything for exclamation,profile,spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature "@Profile" in Spring is actually a feature in "Spring-boots". Read the [Spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for more information on how to configure and use it.

In your example, it simply means that the component or component annotated with `@Profile(“!json”)` is not available if the active profile (set with the property `spring.profiles.active`) is 'json'.

Answer (score 1):

Example in Spring boot

```
@Bean
@Profile("!prod")
public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(IngredientRepository repo,
UserRepository userRepo, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
...
}
```

Here, the exclamation mark (!) negates the profile name. Effectively, it states that the
CommandLineRunner bean will be created if the prod profile isn’t active.